# How does the loss function work in Deep-Q Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

If I understand correctly, in Deep-Q we have two networks: the target-network and the q-network

During the learning step - we calculate,

1. (*next_state*) $\rightarrow$ **target-network** $\rightarrow$ (*future-rewards*)
2. (*state*) $\rightarrow$ **q-network** $\rightarrow$
   (*q-values*)
3. *q-values** = *reward-sample* + $\gamma$ * $\max$*(*future-rewards*)*

Then finally we calculate the loss,

***loss = (q-values* - q-values)^2***

Ok the question is - what prevents the q-network to predict all zeros which would minimize the loss completely?

Note that we set the weights of the target equal to the q-net so its essentially the same network.

Comment: why would predicting zeros minimize the cost? the loss is the squared difference between q-values and the q-values*.

Comment: @gunes I was thinking target and q-network are almost the same network since the weights are transferred every so often - and maybe if the reward is sparse enough - what is stoping the network to produce zeros which would in turn make the loss go to zero. I am probably wrong - I just don't understand it well enough.